# How to determine if Chrome Window is miniminzed from a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension and want to determine if the Chrome Window is minimized. On searching stackoverflow.com I found the following solution, however its not working for me and I get an error: Error in response to windows.get: TypeError: undefined is not a function at chrome-extension:// ......

I have the following code in my background.js

```
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function(windowId) {
    if (windowId === -1) {
         console.window("Minimized");
    } else {
        chrome.windows.get(windowId, function(chromeWindow) {
            if (chromeWindow.state === "minimized") {
                console.window("Minimized");
            } else {
                console.window("NOT Minimized");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Are there any special permissions that I should add to the manifest to make the above code work? Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is almost obvious: what are you doing there on line #3, #7 and #9? There is no such `console.window()` function... that's why you are getting that error: because the property `window` of the object `console` is obviously undefined. It looks like you are trying to log some information, but you use the wrong function. **What you want is `console.log()`**.

Here is the correct code:

```
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function(windowId) {
    if (windowId === -1) {
         console.log("Minimized");
    } else {
        chrome.windows.get(windowId, function(chromeWindow) {
            if (chromeWindow.state === "minimized") {
                console.log("Minimized");
            } else {
                console.log("NOT Minimized");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Plus, quoting from documentation:

> When requested, a `windows.Window` will contain an array of `tabs.Tab` objects. You must declare the `"tabs"` permission in your manifest if you require access to the `url`, `title`, or `favIconUrl` properties of `tabs.Tab`.

So, **if you also want to access the windows' tabs, you'll have to add the permission in your manifest:**

```
...
"permissions": [
    "tabs", ...
],
...
```

**NOTE**: you'll never get it to log `"Minimized"`, because the `onFocusChanged` event is only fired when some window gets focused, not when loses focus. If you want to see if any window is minimized you'll have to use the `chrome.windows.getAll()` method and iterate over the various windows to check whether they are minimized or not.

---

**Addendum**: to check which windows are minimized:

```
function doSomethingWithMinimizedWindows(windows) {
    for (var i = 0; i < windows.length; i++) {
        // do something with windows[i]
        // for example:
        console.log('Window #'+windows[i].id+' is minimized!');
    }
}

chrome.windows.getAll(function(windows) {
    var minimized = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < windows.length; i++) {
        if (windows[i].state === "minimized") {
            minimized.push(windows[i]);
        }
    }

    doSomethingWithMinimizedWindows(minimized);
});
```

The above code will produce something like the following:

```
 Window #378 is minimized!
 Window #457 is minimized!
 Window #460 is minimized!
 Window #463 is minimized!
```

Comment: You are correct again it never logs "Minimized" and I basically want to check if its minimized. Can you please explain me with some code how to check if all tabs are minimized with chrome.windows.getAll() Thanks for you time, I really appreciate all your help.

Comment: @bluenile edited my answer, hope this helped. If so, consider marking it as correct to let other people find it easily.

Comment: 'The chrome.windows API can be used without declaring any permission. However, the "tabs" permission is required in order to populate the url, title, and favIconUrl properties of Tab objects.' https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows

Comment: @rsanchez thanks for the clarification, I added it to my answer.